# How dspace batch metadata edit is safe from producing data inconsistencies?

Tags: dspace

I wonder how is handled batch metadata edit in dspace, such that data inconsistency is avoided.

More specifically, let's say that I have an item that is archived. but still in the review workflow.

Let's say someone is reviewing the metadata of an item, while a batch edit is being done by someone else.

I wonder what happens in that case.

Indeed, this person will have a page with some metadata value that will be changed in the background.

What happens when that person save the item? Does it erase the operation of the batch edit?

I need to implement a functionality similar to the batch edit, that is, an operation that will change some record on the background from time to time. It has to do with Taxonomy management. Hence, I wonder what are my options to update item metadata values in the background, such that is does not interfere with eventually item that are being reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there are safeguards in place for this type of scenario. Is it an option to run the background work outside of reviewers' work hours? Or would it be an option for you to do your background work as a curation task hooked into the review workflow?

Comment: Well the Taxonomy gets updated anytime, hence we can't rely on the curation task. Unless this could be done programmatically. Meaning launching a curation task programmatically whenever necessary.

Comment: I guess my question is, do you _need_ the update to happen at any time, or is it ok for the update to happen just at transition points between workflow states. You can run a curation task programatically whenever you want https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC18/Curation+System#CurationSystem-Onthecommandline but again I don't think that'll prevent your scenario of changes happening concurrently.